# How do i display a variable from a XML document using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

So I got this XML file:

```
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <TITLE Name="123">Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Greatest Hits</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dolly Parton</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>RCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1982</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Still got the blues</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Gary Moore</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Virgin records</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Eros</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Eros Ramazzotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>BMG</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>One night only</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bee Gees</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1998</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Sylvias Mother</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Dr.Hook</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>CBS</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.10</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1973</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Maggie May</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Rod Stewart</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Pickwick</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.50</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Romanza</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Andrea Bocelli</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>When a man loves a woman</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Percy Sledge</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Black angel</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Savage Rose</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mega</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>1999 Grammy Nominees</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Many</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Grammy</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1999</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>For the good times</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kenny Rogers</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Mucik Master</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.70</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1995</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Big Willie style</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Will Smith</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1997</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Tupelo Honey</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Van Morrison</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Polydor</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1971</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Soulsville</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Jorn Hoel</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>Norway</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>WEA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1996</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>The very best of</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Cat Stevens</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Island</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1990</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Stop</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Sam Brown</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>A and M</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Bridge of Spies</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>T'Pau</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Siren</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Private Dancer</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Tina Turner</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Capitol</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Midt om natten</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Kim Larsen</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Medley</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1983</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Pavarotti Gala Concert</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Luciano Pavarotti</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>DECCA</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1991</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>The dock of the bay</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Otis Redding</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Atlantic</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Picture book</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Simply Red</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>EU</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Elektra</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Red</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>The Communards</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>London</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>7.80</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Unchain my heart</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Joe Cocker</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>EMI</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>8.20</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1987</YEAR>
</CD>
```

And this is my HTML/JavaScript File:

```
<!DOCTYPEHTLM>
<html>
  <head>
<!-- General -->
<title>XML</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></meta>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"></meta>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","AL4032721.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
i=0;

function displayCD()
{
artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
txt1=artist;
txt2=title;
txt3=year;
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML=txt1;
document.getElementById("2").innerHTML=txt2;
document.getElementById("3").innerHTML=txt3;
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body onload="displayCD()">
<h2>Machines</h2>

<div class="list-group col-lg-2">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">14</span><span id="1"></span></a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">14</span><span id="2"></span></a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">14</span><span id="3"></span></a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">14</span><span id="to"></span>1</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><span class="badge">14</span><span id="to">            </span>1</a>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So what I wanna do is to take the value of the variable "Name" of the Title tag in the XML document and display it on the HTML site. Right now the code works fine for displaying the value of all the tags, but I can't figure out how to make it display the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('TITLE');
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  alert(x[i].getAttribute('Name'));

document.write(x[i].getAttribute('Name'));
document.write("<br>");
}
```

More infor: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getattribute.asp